# Can If Statment created based on loop?

Tags: php

For example

```
$InitArray[1] = 4;
$InitArray[2] = 5;
$InitArray[3] = 6;
```

I want to make if statment with that syntax

```
if($Type = /* key */){
 $Position = /* value */
}
```

which means

```
if($Type = 1){
  $Position = 4;
}
if($Type = 2){
  $Position = 5;
}
if($Type = 3){
  $Position = 6;
}
```

How to make that if statment through array loop?

Edit :

Array isn't static , User put his own array
,It Could be like that for example

```
$InitArray[4] = 34;
$InitArray[5] = 13;
```

or

```
$InitArray[6]  = 12;
$InitArray[13] = 84;
$InitArray[52] = 23;
$InitArray[78] = 10;
```

what I mean is something like this

```
foreach($InitArray as $TypeWritten => $PositionWritten){
  if($Type = $TypeWritten){
    $Position = $PositionWritten;
  }
}
```

Comment: `$Position = $InitArray[$Type];`?

Comment: Where do you plan to use the variable `$Position`? It seems pointless to keep defining `$Position` with new value without actually using it.

Comment: dont forget the `==` or `===` operators for comparing values, `=` is for assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Equal comparison operator in php is double equal sign `==`. So you need to at least change all if statement to use `==` instead of `=`.

```php
foreach($InitArray as $TypeWritten => $PositionWritten){
  if($Type == $TypeWritten){
    $Position = $PositionWritten;

    // some code to use the $Position variable ...
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing the correct comparison operator. Just change the `=` into `==` (or `===` if the variables you are comparing are of the same type),

```
foreach($InitArray as $TypeWritten => $PositionWritten){
  if($Type == $TypeWritten){
    $Position = $PositionWritten;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps,